# SQL-запрос: помогите изменить SELECT на JOIN

Tags: sql, select, join, mariadb

У меня есть вот такой SQL-запрос:

```
select b.id,
       b.user_id,
       b.fio,
       b.source_id,
       b.user_IP,
       (select count(distinct a.user_id) from AuthLog as a where a.user_IP = b.user_IP) as amount_by_IP,
       b.ip_region
from AuthLog b
order by b.id
limit 100, 20;
```

Как мы видим, запрос делает выборку, в которой он использует внутренний `SELECT`. Этот селект подсчитывает, сколько совпадений по базе по полю `user_IP`. Мне нужно убрать внутренний `SELECT` и переписать запрос с использованием `JOIN`. Подскажите, как это можно сделать?

Comment: Укажите точную версию СУБД.

Comment: Какая-то MariaDB, но менять её смысла нет, потому что на проде ещё древнее.

Answer (score 3):

Жаль, MySQL (и СУБД на его основе) не поддерживает оконные функции и CROSS/OUTER APPLY. Можно в принципе как-то так, наверное (в MySQL не очень силен)

```
select b.id,
       b.user_id,
       b.fio,
       b.source_id,
       b.user_IP,
       a.amount_by_IP,
       b.ip_region
from AuthLog b
left join (select user_IP, count(distinct a.user_id) as amount_by_IP from AuthLog group by user_IP) as a on a.user_IP = b.user_IP
order by b.id
limit 100, 20;
```

Или можно использовать обобщенные таблицы:

```
WITH CTE AS (
  select user_IP, count(distinct a.user_id) as amount_by_IP 
  from AuthLog 
  group by user_IP
)
select b.id,
       b.user_id,
       b.fio,
       b.source_id,
       b.user_IP,
       a.amount_by_IP,
       b.ip_region
from AuthLog b
left join CTE as a on a.user_IP = b.user_IP
order by b.id
limit 100, 20;
```

Comment: *Жаль, MySQL (и СУБД на его основе) не поддерживает оконные функции* Версия 8+ поддерживает.

Comment: Обобщённые таблицы моя версия MariaDB не поддерживает. А запрос с джоинами стал выполняться в 5 раз дольше. Но спасибо за ответ :)

Comment: @ВячеславЧернышов, не за что. Может и не стоит ничего менять в вашем запросе? В чем вообще причина не использовать подзапрос? Была мысль, что с JOIN'ом будет дольше выпоняться, но вы просили именно JOIN. Грустно, что и обобщенные не поддерживает.

Answer (score 2):

Наверное,

```
select id,
       user_id,
       fio,
       source_id,
       user_IP,
       count(distinct user_id) OVER (PARTITION BY user_IP) as amount_by_IP,
       ip_region
from AuthLog
order by id
limit 100, 20;
```

---

> К сожалению, моя версия MariaDB не поддерживает window function.

Тогда попробуйте

```
select b.id,
       b.user_id,
       b.fio,
       b.source_id,
       b.user_IP,
       count(distinct a.user_id) as amount_by_IP,
       b.ip_region
from AuthLog b
JOIN AuthLog as a ON a.user_IP = b.user_IP)
GROUP BY b.id /* ,b.user_id,b.fio,b.source_id,b.user_IP,b.ip_region */
order by b.id
limit 100, 20;
```

Comment: К сожалению, моя версия MariaDB не поддерживает window function.

Comment: @ВячеславЧернышов Переписал на JOIN - опробуйте.

Comment: запрос уходит в бесконечное выполнение

Comment: @ВячеславЧернышов Так дофига записей? И индекс по `(user_IP, id)` не помогает? Тогда остаётся только первый вариант из [ответа](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/933175/229437) [Vasil Baymurzin](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/178618/vasil-baymurzin).